# Update content inside InfoBox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I'm using one InfoBox for every marker because I only want one infoBox to appear at a time.

My question is: how do I update the content for the infoBox without creating a completely new infoBox?

I don't want to update content by creating a new infoBox because doing this creates a new infoBox instance which means there can be multiple infoBoxs open at any one time.

Is there any sort of setContent method available or some sort of redraw method which forces the infoBox to update the content set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
that.infobox.setContent(content);
```

Comment: can I pass function calls within "content" ?